# JQuery video frame scrubber control with popcorn-js on mobile?

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, html5-video, popcornjs, kendo-mobile

I'm developing a phonegap app for iOS and Android that I need to let the user scrub backwards and forwards between video frames. Ideally I would like a 'thumb-wheel' type control at the bottom of the mobile screen with the video shown above it.

Popcorn-js looks like it may be able to do this but I can't figure out how to step forwards or backwards through the frames in the source videos.

I'm using HTML5/CSS3/Kendo-Mobile etc.

Any help/example javascript/html would be much appreciated!!

Regards
Stu

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure about frames but you can set (and get) the position of the video in time

```
// go to 30 seconds 
popcorn.currentTime(30);

// move on 5 seconds 
popcorn.currentTime(p.currentTime()+5  );

// go back 15 seconds 
popcorn.currentTime(p.currentTime()-15  );
```